# Can I install CyanoGenMod's or AOSP Messaging app on top of existing Messaging app by my vendor

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, 4.4-kitkat

I want to install default Android SMS/Messaging app by Google, or even the one that comes with CyanoGenMod Custom ROMs.
They feel more native and plain, which is awesome.

Can I have 2 Messaging apps on my Galaxy S4 (I9500) without problems, or disable Samsung's messaging app and install AOSP/CM's Messaging app?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Kitkat, you can make one app the default SMS app. By default, on a device with Google apps, that is Hangouts, but you can install as many SMS apps as you like. If they have been developed/updated for Kitkat, they should be fitted to be used as "default SMS app".

Of course, if you don't need one of the pre-installed apps, or don't want to use it at all, you can go to *Settings→Apps* and see whether it can be disabled (some pre-installed bloatware is protected against this).

Answer (score 0):

You can find Google's SMS/MMS app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging).

It basically is AOSP messaging, it also has updates too!

Comment: Well, now. But this was not true when I posted the question!

Comment: That is a 50+MB app though - to send SMS.. seriously, Google? If it was AOSP, then it has evolved/bloated beyond all recognition.